# Web Api does not receive posts

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I have spent the better part of a day, and my teacher has also been unable to figure this issue out..

I have a c# Web Api 2 project, where i'm trying to Post with "postman", to the project locally on my machine.. Gets work without issue but post only works if i pass no parameters...

**My Action in my SystemsController**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] SystemModel data)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest("The request was not formatted correctly");
            }

        using (ModelContainer entities = new ModelContainer())
        {
            entities.Systems.Add(new Systems()
            {
                Name = data.Name,
                Description = data.Description,
                Longtitude = data.Longtitude,
                Latitude = data.Latitude,
                Brometer = data.Brometer,
                Imagepath = data.Imagepath,
            });

            entities.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

**My Model:**

```
public class SystemModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Longtitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Brometer { get; set; }
        public string Imagepath { get; set; }
    }
```

**The Json in Postman:**

```
{
    "Name":"Dette er en test", 
    "Description": "en beskrivelse",
    "Longtitude": "31.0200",
    "Latitude": "-121.00",
    "Brometer": "1025.31",
    "ImagePath": "somepath/to/image.jpg"
}
```

No matter what i do i never hit the post action..

My Url i post to is localhost:44389/api/Systems

I'm at a loss.. googleing around has brought no solution at all so far.. 
As far as i can see i am doing it correctly.. or ?

**Update**
So i tried changing IHttpActionResult to SystemModel, and then just return the data... and now it works... why, i have no idea !?!

So i looks like this now...

```
 [HttpPost]
        public SystemModel Post(SystemModel data)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return null;
            }

            using (ModelContainer entities = new ModelContainer())
            {
                var record = new Systems()
                {
                    Name = data.Name,
                    Description = data.Description,
                    Longtitude = data.Longtitude,
                    Latitude = data.Latitude,
                    Brometer = data.Brometer,
                    Imagepath = data.Imagepath,
                };
                entities.Systems.Add(record);

                entities.SaveChanges();

                return new SystemModel() // returns the inserted object
                {
                    Id = record.Id,
                    Name = record.Name,
                    Description = record.Description,
                    Longtitude = record.Longtitude ?? default(double),
                    Latitude = record.Latitude ?? default(double),
                    Brometer = record.Brometer ?? default(double),
                    Imagepath = record.Imagepath,
                };
            }
        }
```

Comment: try changing your json, so that all propertynames start with a lowercase. You also don't need the [FromBody] part in your parameters

Comment: tried changing it but no difference

Comment: Also, Imagepath has a capital P in your Json, change that too. what's the response you are getting in postman?

Comment: i set the imagepath and tried again, but no difference, postman just keeps running, it does not say anything, so i have to cancel it each time..

Comment: does it hit a breakpoint in the controller?

Comment: on the get actions, yes, but not on the post. And i just tried creating a asp.net.core api project, and in that i can hit the post with no problem...

Comment: Are there any messages in the server-side log?

Comment: im running the application locally

Comment: You can still see output in the console in visual studio then. can you update your question with correct json?

Comment: In my Console ? The project is a .net framework web application.

Comment: Okey so i changed IHttpActionResult  to systemmodel, and then just returned the object... and now it works... why ?

Comment: Possible routing issue? Have you tried setting an explicit route, or posting to `localhost:44389/api/Systems/Post` or `localhost:44389/Systems/` etc...

Comment: yep, i tried setting specific routes with [Route("name/of/route")] and that changed nothing..

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Content-Type` to `application/json` in the Headers

and the json in postman is

```
{
"Name":"Dette er en test", 
"Description": "en beskrivelse",
"Longtitude": 31.0200,
"Latitude": -121.00,
"Brometer": 1025.31,
"ImagePath": "somepath/to/image.jpg"
}
```